# Passport - Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, passport.js

I know variations of this questions have been asked multiple times. My understanding is that you basically have to watch your if/else logic and make sure that `done` isn't being called multiple times.

Twitter and Google work fine. Facebook is giving me this error though:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/azerner/code/mean-starter/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:718:10)
    at ServerResponse.location (/Users/azerner/code/mean-starter/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:835:8)
    at ServerResponse.redirect (/Users/azerner/code/mean-starter/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:874:8)
    at complete (/Users/azerner/code/mean-starter/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:241:26)
    at /Users/azerner/code/mean-starter/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:250:15
    at pass (/Users/azerner/code/mean-starter/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:427:14)
    at Authenticator.transformAuthInfo (/Users/azerner/code/mean-starter/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:449:5)
    at /Users/azerner/code/mean-starter/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:247:22
    at /Users/azerner/code/mean-starter/node_modules/passport/lib/http/request.js:51:7
    at pass (/Users/azerner/code/mean-starter/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:273:43)
    at serialized (/Users/azerner/code/mean-starter/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:282:7)
    at /Users/azerner/code/mean-starter/server/passport.js:17:5
    at pass (/Users/azerner/code/mean-starter/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:290:9)
    at Authenticator.serializeUser (/Users/azerner/code/mean-starter/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:295:5)
    at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (/Users/azerner/code/mean-starter/node_modules/passport/lib/http/request.js:48:29)
```

**passport.js**

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
var TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('User');
var Local = mongoose.model('Local');
var Facebook = mongoose.model('Facebook');
var Twitter = mongoose.model('Twitter');
var Google = mongoose.model('Google');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var config = require('./config.json');

module.exports = function(passport) {
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user._id);
  });
  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User
      .findById(id).populate('local').exec()
      .then(function(user) {
        console.log('deserializeUser found user: ', user);
        done(null, user);
      }, done)
    ;
  });

  // LOCAL
  passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
    Local
      .findOne({ username: username })
      .select('username role hashedPassword')
      .exec()
      .then(function(local) {
        if (!local) {
          return done(null, false);
        }
        var validPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(password, local.hashedPassword);
        if (!validPassword) {
          return done(null, false);
        }
        else {
          User
            .findOne({ local: local })
            .populate('local')
            .exec()
            .then(function(user) {
              return done(null, user);
            })
          ;
        }
      })
    ;
  }));

  // FACEBOOK
  passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: config.facebookAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret: config.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: config.facebookAuth.callbackURL
  }, function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    // asynchronous
    process.nextTick(function() {
      Facebook
        .findOne({ id: profile.id })
        .select('id token')
        .exec()
        .then(function(facebook) {
          if (facebook) {
            User
              .findOne({ facebook: facebook._id }).exec()
              .then(function(user) {
                return done(null, user);
              })
            ;
          }
          else {
            Facebook
              .create({ id: profile.id, token: token })
              .then(function(createdFacebook) {
                User
                  .create({ facebook: createdFacebook })
                  .then(function(user) {
                    return done(null, user);
                  })
                ;
              })
            ;
          }
        })
        .then(function(err) {
          return done(err);
        })
      ;
    });
  }));

  // TWITTER
  passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: config.twitterAuth.consumerKey,
    consumerSecret: config.twitterAuth.consumerSecret,
    callbackURL: config.twitterAuth.callbackURL
  }, function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
      Twitter
        .findOne({ id: profile.id })
        .select('id token')
        .exec()
        .then(function(twitter) {
          if (twitter) {
            User
              .findOne({ twitter: twitter._id }).exec()
              .then(function(user) {
                return done(null, user);
              })
            ;
          }
          else {
            Twitter
              .create({ id: profile.id, token: token })
              .then(function(createdTwitter) {
                User
                  .create({ twitter: createdTwitter })
                  .then(function(user) {
                    return done(null, user);
                  })
                ;
              })
            ;
          }
        })
        .then(null, function(err) {
          return done(err);
        })
      ;
    });
  }));

  // GOOGLE
  passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: config.googleAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret: config.googleAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: config.googleAuth.callbackURL
  }, function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
      Google
        .findOne({ id: profile.id })
        .select('id token')
        .exec()
        .then(function(google) {
          if (google) {
            User
              .findOne({ google: google._id }).exec()
              .then(function(user) {
                return done(null, user);
              })
            ;
          }
          else {
            Google
              .create({ id: profile.id, token: token })
              .then(function(createdGoogle) {
                User
                  .create({ google: createdGoogle })
                  .then(function(user) {
                    return done(null, user);
                  })
                ;
              })
            ;
          }
        })
        .then(null, function(err) {
          return done(err);
        })
      ;
    });
  }));
};
```

**auth.routes.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var Auth = require('./auth.service.js');
try {
  var User = mongoose.model('User');
}
catch(e) {
  var User = mongoose.model('User', require('../users/user.model.js').UserSchema);
}
var router = express.Router();

// LOCAL
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json(req.user);
});

router.get('/logout', Auth.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  req.logout();
  res.status(204).end();
});

router.get('/current-user', Auth.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json(req.user);
});

// FACEBOOK
router.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));
router.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login'
  })
);

// TWITTER
router.get('/auth/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter'));
router.get('/auth/twitter/callback',
  passport.authenticate('twitter', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login'
  })
);

// GOOGLE
router.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile'] }));
router.get('/auth/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login'
  })
);

module.exports = router;
```

It's also worth noting that I have been using [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Block-a-Specific-Website-Without-Software) to block Facebook, but I unblocked it to work on this. I did the commands, force quit Chrome and reopened it, and now I can log into facebook.com fine.

Edit: Oh, and I checked MongoHub and it shows that the User (and Facebook subdocument) have been created.

Comment: This particular error occurs when you are trying to send a response to a particular request a second time after it has already been sent.  This pretty much always happens because of incorrect handling of async responses which messes up the order of execution to cause the above issue.

Comment: @jfriend00 I know that, but I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong. Especially why my code for Facebook and Twitter/Google are the same, but the latter works while the former doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the passport flow enough to be able to help.  I was just trying to help you know what to look for.

Comment: @jfriend00 no problem :)